# why does logstash stops processing logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

Logstash stops processing logs after some hours. When logs stops processing logstash service consumes high amount of CPU performance (about 25 cores of 32 total).
When logstash service works normal it consumes about 4-5 cores total.
Pipeline generates about 50k events per minute.
Logstash Conf (non default):
pipeline.workers: 15
pipeline.batch.size: 100
JVM CONF:
-Xms15g
-Xmx15g

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5044
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5044
    type => syslog
  }
}


filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NOTSPACE:syslog_timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" ]
    }
    kv {
      id => "logs_kv"
      source => "syslog_message"
      trim_key => " "
      trim_value => " "
      value_split => "="
      field_split => " "
    }

  mutate {
     remove_field  => [ "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
    }

    #now check if source IP is a private IP, if so, tag it   
    cidr {
      address => [ "%{srcip}" ]
      add_tag => [ "src_internalIP" ]
      network => [ "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16" ]
    }

    # don't run geoip if it's internalIP, otherwise find the GEOIP location
    if "src_internalIP" not in [tags] {
      geoip {
        add_tag => [ "src_geoip" ]
        source => "srcip"
    database => "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/ingest-geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
      }
      geoip {
        source => "srcip"
    database => "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/ingest-geoip/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb"
      }

    } 
    else {
      #check DST IP now.  If it is a private IP, tag it 
      cidr {
        add_tag => [ "dst_internalIP" ]
        address => [ "%{dstip}" ]
        network => [ "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16" ]
      }

      # don't run geoip if it's internalIP, otherwise find the GEOIP location
      if "dst_internalIP" not in [tags] {
        geoip {
          add_tag => [ "dst_geoip" ]
          source => "dstip"
    database => "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/ingest-geoip/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"
        }
        geoip {
          source => "dstip"
    database => "/usr/share/elasticsearch/modules/ingest-geoip/GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output {
if [type] == "syslog" {

  elasticsearch {hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200" ]
        index         => "sysl-%{syslog_hostname}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
#stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
}
```

When logstash stops processing i dont see any errors in log file (log level - trace). Only see these messages:

```
[2019-04-19T00:00:12,004][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:17,011][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:17,012][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:22,015][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:22,015][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:27,023][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:27,024][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:32,030][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-04-19T00:00:32,030][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
```

events format:

```
[2019-04-22T13:04:27,190][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] filter received {"event"=>{"type"=>"syslog", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>2019-04-22T10:04:27.159Z, "port"=>50892, "message"=>"<30>2019:04:22-13:05:08 msk ulogd[18998]: id=\"2002\" severity=\"info\" sys=\"SecureNet\" sub=\"packetfilter\" name=\"Packet accepted\" action=\"accept\" fwrule=\"6\" initf=\"eth2\" outitf=\"eth1\" srcmac=\"70:79:b3:ab:e0:e8\" dstmac=\"00:1a:8c:f0:89:02\" srcip=\"10.0.134.138\" dstip=\"10.0.131.134\" proto=\"17\" length=\"66\" tos=\"0x00\" prec=\"0x00\" ttl=\"126\" srcport=\"63936\" dstport=\"53\" ", "host"=>"10.0.130.235"}}
```

Help me please debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet, the ParNew garbage collector is "stop the world".  If it takes 5 seconds to resume, and you're getting GC every 5 seconds, you'll get no throughput from logstash as it's always blocked.

Comment: So how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Problem was in kv filter, which stopped logstash when trying to parse non-structured data going trough pipeline.